# Java concurrency making elevator stop at nearby floors

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized

So for this assignment I must simulate elevators.
Right now, I generate 3 people who are spawned on a random floor and have a random destination floor.
I have 1 elevator that picks them up and brings them.
The problem I have is that the elevator handles 1 person at a time.
I'm not sure how to make it so that the elevator will stop at floors with people on the way.
For example:

Person 1's start floor is 3 and is going to 8
Person 2's start floor is 9 and is going to 10
Person 3's start floor is 6 and is going to 9

The way it works currently, the elevator goes to 3, then goes to 8, without stopping at floor 6 for person 3. I'm not sure how I can fix this problem.

The code for the elevator moving between floors is like this:

```
public void moveTo(int floor) throws InterruptedException
{
    int distance;

    synchronized(this)
    {
        distance = Math.abs(currentFloor - floor);
        System.out.println(name + " is on floor " + currentFloor + " moving to " + floor);
    }

    Thread.sleep(1000 * distance);

    synchronized(this)
    {
        currentFloor = floor;
    }
}
```

And the main run() method for the elevator is this:

```
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        for(;;)
        {
            ElevatorTask task;

            synchronized(this)
            {
                while(next_task == null)
                    wait();

                task = next_task;
                next_task = null;
                notify();
            }

            moveTo(task.getDestination());
        }
    }
    catch(InterruptedException ex){}
}
```

Any help with this would be great.
Thanks

Comment: How are the destinations ordered?  If you need to stop at 6 and 9, where is the logic that will decide to stop at 6 first, based on the fact that you're currently at 3?  Ie, what is "getDestination"?

Comment: I envision the elevator's described by enums, ElevatorMotionState: STOPPED, MOVING; ElevatorDirectionState: HEADING_UP, HEADING_DOWN as well as have a double value for location. I envision another class, ElevatorControl that accepts requests for floors, requests to catch the elevator going up or going down, that these requests would be placed into some queue of some type, perhaps a sorted queue, sorted by floors.

Comment: A fair algorithm for this that avoids infinite wait times is actually a rather complex problem.

Comment: @HotLicks So I have an ElevatorTask class that takes the destination and has a method to return the elevators destination, and in the Elevator class I have a next_task which is in the run delivery task method, that has the elevator wait until there is a task.
So in the main method I have this:

panels[people[0].GetCurrentFloor()].pressButton().getButtonPanel().pressButton(people[0].GetDestinationFloor());

So it basically calls the elevator to the persons current floor with PressButton(), which also moves the elevator to the destinatino floor

Comment: @Voo Yeah it is quite complex, its a pretty big assignment, and programming isn't a strong point for me so all this concurrency stuff boggles my mind

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yeah that sounds similar to the way it is working. I do have a ElevatorController class that does a lot of stuff. Im fairly lost with everything to be honest haha don't know where to start

Comment: Forget the concurrency.  Work it out in your head and on paper what you would do if you were a "master elevator operator" radioing other elevator operators to tell them what floors to stop on.

Comment: Thats not a bad idea i should really do that. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Just thinking:

When your elevator is next to a floor, check if there is someone there. If yes, open the doors, if no, skip to the next floor.

After you send all of your persons to their floors, go to the most near floor that has an person calling the lift.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah I understand what you mean just have to figure out how to do it in the code.